# How to add watermarks on an image in iphone

Tags: iphone, image, watermark

I want to add watermarks on an `UIImage`.

For that i have googled and also studied questions on this website like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4068035/how-to-add-watermark-on-a-exist-image)
But did not get any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add image on your image view and then add one subview on it and set alpha of subview less so it look like water mark or you can add label, but in label you have to change its angel to show angular

Comment: UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum([NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/IMG_0026.MOV", [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]], nil, nil, nil);

Comment: void UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum (
   UIImage  *image,
   id       completionTarget,
   SEL      completionSelector,
   void     *contextInfo
);

Comment: What if you want to retain the original resolution of the image?  If the image is much bigger than the area in which you display it and apply the watermark, is it also downscaled when you save it?

Answer (score 0):

If your UIImage is suppose in the imageview and watermark image in the imageview1, then use method of UIView class
[imageview addSubview: imageview1];
.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
//get image width and height
int w = img.size.width;
int h = img.size.height;
CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
//create a graphic context with CGBitmapContextCreate
CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(NULL, w, h, 8, 4 * w, colorSpace, kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst);
CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, w, h), img.CGImage);
CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1);
char* text = (char *)[text1 cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
CGContextSelectFont(context, "Georgia", 30, kCGEncodingMacRoman);
CGContextSetTextDrawingMode(context, kCGTextFill);
CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 255, 0, 0, 1);
CGContextSetTextMatrix(context, CGAffineTransformMakeRotation( -M_PI/4 ));
CGContextShowTextAtPoint(context, 40, 20, text, strlen(text));
//Create image ref from the context
CGImageRef imageMasked = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context);
CGContextRelease(context);
CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
return [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageMasked];
```