# Limiting the user from saving the screen

Tags: ios, iphone

I am making an app that allows the user to add captions to their photos. I'd like to be able to allow the user to save / share 3 of their creations, and after they share for the third time, shut down the app until they purchase more credits.

I'm trying to think of ways that the user can get around this to use my app for free all the time. The only way I can think that the user can save a photo manually is to do a screen shot, which I know how to detect so I'm not worried about. Is there anything else I'm not thinking of?

Comment: what if they delete then reinstall your app?

Comment: @JamesP - I think you can use the keychain to prevent this

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in an indirect way like the Snapchat app. Taking a screenshot interrupts any screen touches. See [this](http://tumblr.jeremyjohnstone.com/post/38503925370/how-to-detect-screenshots-on-ios-like-snapchat) for the solution.

Comment: This relies on undocumented API which could change anytime.

Answer (score -1):

You can trap the screen shot event and if they do create a screen shot you can delete it.

Comment: I'm pretty certain that this is not true on iOS. You can *access* the user's photo roll — if you ask for permission first! — but I'm not aware of any way that you can delete their photos.

Answer (score -1):

You can display some watermarks [image: overlay or masked over your UIImageView] .

Remove watermark only after they buy it.

Here is a [stackoverflow link to add watermarks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4068035/how-to-add-watermark-on-a-exist-image)