# Xcode swift add watermark to image

Tags: xcode, swift, watermark

My app allows the user to take a picture and share/save it, but I want to know if it is possible to add a watermark to the image beforehand. I am guessing I would need to create a transparent watermark image and somehow layer it with the image the user takes then save it.

Comment: maybe, this can give you help? - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4068035/how-to-add-watermark-on-a-exist-image

Comment: Convert your image to a CIImage and take a look at the [Core Image](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/CoreImaging/CoreImage.pdf) reference, I think for this it works better than Core Graphics