# how to add Sticker on Image in IOS using Swift?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I am developing a drawing iOS application. In that I want to add a **sticker(image)** to Image, then I can **save the images**.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to add watermark on a exist image](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4068035/how-to-add-watermark-on-a-exist-image)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try These Steps

Step 1 - have a UIView as a parent, let's say stickerView
Step 2 - add image to stickerView
Step 3 - add stickers to stickerView
Step 4 - save a snapshot of stickerView

The code for UIView,

```
extension UIImage {
class func imageWithView(view: UIView) -> UIImage {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.bounds.size, view.opaque, 0.0)
    view.drawViewHierarchyInRect(view.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)
    let img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    return img
  }
}
```

Usage

```
let snapshotImage = UIImage.imageWithView(stickerView)
```

Try This code Hope it will help

Comment: i am working on photo editing app and what if i want to add multiple stickers and remove all stickers when ever i click on reset button. in this senario i have performing same way as you have mentioned above but i have created global variable for stickers so that i was unable to add multiple stickers how can i add multiple stickers. @Abdul

Answer (score 1):

Don't modify the image itself. Instead, add another `UIImageView` with sticker above the original `UIImageView` with the image.